# SWIFTUI Understanding using CoreData Objects in a model (MVVM)

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

I am a little bit confused how to use core data objects in a model.
Let's say I have a game as my model. This model is initialised with a couple of players. This players are objects in my database handelt by CoreData. While the game is ruining the statistics of each player (also stored in my database) is updated. So how can I handle this to confirm to the MVVM pattern? Should I pass my player objects from CoreData to my model using my viewModel (for the game) or should I create extra structs for my players in the game and create them from my CoreData objects. I also want to store every moves players are making in a table, so I need to use my CoreData objects somehow in my model. I am a little bit confused here. Can someone help me out? Maybe with a short example how to solve such a topic.

Comment: This question is a bit too open-ended for SO. But when you start a new project in Xcode it gives you a good starting point to work with CoreData. After that CoreData Objects are `ObservableObjects` so when you look at the [Apple SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/) anywhere you see an `ObservedObject`, `EnvironmentObject`, or `StateObject` you can apply that process to a CoreData object.

Comment: Ok, thx. Seems that i have to take a deep breath and dive down in this deep hole. ;)